# Jquery UI datepicker shows on bottom in mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

Please see the page link: http://checkmyryde.com/rent.php

I have used Jquery ui datepicker, it is working fine with desktop view. But if open the page in mobile device, datepicker positioning at the bottom of the page. What might be the issue here? any idea? Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


$('.date-picker').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  


<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="date-picker"></p>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share your relevant code ? css and html for the datepicker .

Comment: @MihaiT yes....

Answer (score 0):

without any code to work with , my guess it that the `datepicker calendar` is positioned absolutely with `top:100%` relative to the entire row . So when the items in the row go one below the other one , the datepicker is still positioned relative to the row.

you will need to set it relative to its input, or with jQuery set it's top position equal with the input top position + input height .

EDIT : add `position:relative` to the `p` or `container` that holds the `date-picker input`

Comment: It is working fine in all width of desktop browser, but issue only in mobile device...

Comment: i understand. but i cannot replicate your problem in mobile device, using your code try : 

add `position:relative` to the `p` or `container` that holds the `date-picker input`

Answer (score 0):

As JQuery autodetect screen, no need to modified in jquery-ui. still if you need to override there is already soluton availableon below link.
[click here to view original issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488404/jquery-datepicker)

```
(function() {
   var orig = jQuery.datepicker._showDatepicker;
   jQuery.datepicker._showDatepicker = function(input){
       orig.apply(this, arguments);
       $('#ui-datepicker-div').css('top', '100px');
    }
});
```

You might be change `top` value according to your requirement.